# FAT32 R/W performance too low for a big file transfer

Tags: kernel, filesystem, performance, fat32

I have mounted FAT32 formatted USB storage to ext4 FS and executed a large file copy operation.

Observed that FAT32 R/W performance to ext4 partition is very much slower 
than same ext4 partitions.

I've tried various combinations of with mount with ASYNC option and increased the FAT cluster but it didn't help.

Debugged the v4.4.84 kernel and looks like following functions are taking more time:

```
fat_write_end(){ 
   ...
      block_write_end(){
        ... 
        grab_page_cache_write_begin(){
            ...

        }   //+96.923us

    }   //+168.089us

 }  //+189.778us
```

I have used simple copy command. File size is 256 MB with bs of 64K.

Could you please suggest how to improve the performance?

Comment: Updated my queries . Hope my query is clear now.

Comment: Thanks for the asking. I have used simple copy command. File size is 256 mb with bs of 64K.

Comment: Any input how can i improve the performance or is it a known issue ?
Even i have noticed that ext4<->ext4 is 10 times faster that ext4<->fat .